# Looking for Android app for Remote Control PC (Windows)

Tags: android, remote, remote-access

Requirements:
1) Working through Local Network (preferably). I need this for fast connect to my PC. Apps like TeamViewer or Google Remote Desktop has to long connect to my PC (probably because of connection through Internet)
2) Picture of desktop from PC in real-time (like in TeamViewer)
3) Easy mouse control

I'm using android OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about remote desktop, all the best Android apps are paid apps.  I use VNC Viewer for Android by a developer called androidVNC team + Antlersoft.  It works over LAN, assuming you have a direct connection to your LAN, and know IP address of the machine you want to access.

You will also need VNC server, it can be downloaded for free from their site [here](https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/).

Comment: Is there Picture of desktop from PC in real-time?

Comment: If you are on a LAN, yes.  The VNC app degrades the picture quality to best utilize your connection.  If you were to connect over the internet, your picture is degraded to 256 colors on a 512Kbps upload speed.  Your question bugs me a bit... do you intend to try and play movies on the pc and watch them on your Android device?

Comment: I cannot connect. VNC Connection failed! Server did not offer supported security type. I don't know which password i have to use for connection and which username for windows Authentication.

Comment: I run mine without security. If memory serves you specify the username and password on vnc server, has nothing to do with Windows authentication...

Comment: It doesn't work for me. With or without security. But it works fine with another app for android - VNC Viewer. But there is no mouse speed setup. But it connect fine.

Comment: Mine works fine.

Comment: I disable all security in VNC Server and now it works. But tha latency is really bad. Mose move with jerks. I tried other colors mode but it didn't chane anything.

Comment: I use an android phone. Touch interface, no mouse or keyboard. So my mouse doesn't move with jerks.

Comment: Why not just use the one that works fine for you? VNC viewer you said...